# Unexptected '%' rendering a Jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2, code-generation

So, basically I'm running a python script that generates some files. The problem is: every .cpp and .hpp file is being generated without problem, while the script throws an exception generating the CMakeLists.txt, a weird one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "enum_generator.py", line 115, in <module>
  generate_cmakelists(result)
File "enum_generator.py", line 98, in generate_cmakelists
  'templates/cmakelists_enums_template.jinja2', result=result)
File "enum_generator.py", line 43, in render_to_file
  jinja_template = Template(template_file)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 945, in __new__
  return env.from_string(source, template_class=cls)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 880, in from_string
  return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 591, in compile
  self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source_hint)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "<unknown>", line 8, in template
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'
```

I tried the same code, with templates for .cpp and .hpp files, and it works fine. Following you can see the CMake_template and the python script

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(ART_Plugin_Enums)

set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

add_library(ART_Plugin_Enums ${LIBRARY_TYPE}
                        {% for category in result.keys() -%}
                    enums/{{category}}Enum.hpp

                    inc/{{category}}EnumPlugin.hpp
                    inc/{{category}}EnumPlugin_module.hpp

                    src/{{category}}EnumPlugin.cpp
                    src/{{category}}numPlugin_module.cpp
                    {%endfor%})
```

Here's the script:

```
def render_to_file(target_file_path, template_name, *args, **kwargs):
    with open(target_file_path, 'w+') as f:
        template_file = open(os.path.join(SCRIPT_LOCATION,
                                          template_name)).read()
        jinja_template = Template(template_file)
        print("-- Generating {}".format(target_file_path))
        f.write(jinja_template.render(*args, **kwargs))


def generate_cmakelists(result):
    target_file_path = os.path.join(SCRIPT_LOCATION, '..', "CmakeLists.txt")
    return render_to_file(
        target_file_path,
        'templates/cmakelists_enums_template.jinja2', result=result)

generate_cmakelists(result)
```

I'm a lot confused because I can't understand why Jinja is not recognising that % in the for. Any clues?

Comment: Because of the preceding `-`?

Comment: Change `{% for category in result.keys() -%}` to `{% for category in result.keys() %}`.

Comment: Same error, it was the same in the other functioning templates and they worked

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I think I had too many opened files and messed up editing one different from the one that was being rendered. Sorry for making you lose your time, the code actually works.